# How to get popovers in LWC to go across LEX page sections

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, slds, popover

My question is how do I get my [custom popover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m12Fm.png) to span across LEX page sections [like this standard popover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGkxf.png)? I'm using SLDS styling.

LWC html:

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-page-header">
        <div class="slds-page-header__row">
            <div class="slds-page-header__col-title">
                <div class="slds-media">
                    <div class="slds-media__figure">
                        <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-opportunity">
                            <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:contact" size="small"></lightning-icon>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-media__body">
                        <div class="slds-page-header__name">
                            <div class="slds-page-header__name-title">
                                <h4>
                                    <span>Contact</span>
                                    <div class="parent" onmouseover={openPopover} onmouseleave={closePopOver}>
                                        <a class="slds-page-header__title slds-truncate" title="Name" onclick={handleOpenContact} >Hello World</a>
                                        <template if:true={boolShowPopover}>
                                            <section class="slds-popover slds-nubbin_top-left slds-popover_medium testHover" role="dialog" style="position:absolute;"></div>
                                                <header class="slds-popover__header">
                                                    Header           
                                                </header>
                                                <div class="slds-popover__body">
                                                    Body
                                                </div>                                                    
                                            </section>
                                        </template>
                                    </div>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-page-header__col-actions">
                <div class="slds-page-header__controls">
                    <div class="slds-page-header__control">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';

export default class PopoverExample {

    boolShowPopover;

    togglePopover() {
        this.boolShowPopover = !this.boolShowPopover;
    }
    openPopover() {
        this.boolShowPopover = true;
    }

    closePopOver() {
        this.boolShowPopover = false;
    }


}
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve this using CSS that sets the z-index to 9000 for your popover section, which is the [$z-index-modal](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/design-tokens/#category-z-index) value, perhaps like:

```
section.slds-popover { z-index: 9000 }
```

I don't think you can directly use the design tokens with LWC's CSS, hence the suggestion to simply leverage that specific value.

Comment: Hey Phil thanks for the suggestion but I've tried that with no luck. What I ended up doing was split up my LWC here into 2 separate LWCs and wrapped both in Aura components.

After that, I leveraged the lightning:overlayLibrary to create a popover with my popover aura cmp as the content whenever I mouse over my target. Wish it was less of a hassle to do this.

Comment: Hi. That seems very strange. I wonder if there was some other issue involved here not covered in the question detail...

Comment: Have run into this in Angular using the ngbPopover directive. For that environment, the solution was to add `container="body"` to the tag. That associated the popover with the body element allowing it to appear over everything. The z-index property is limited to positioned elements (relative, sticky, absolute, fixed) which is why it didn't work. Have not found a way to connect LWC popovers to the body. Seems like that would be blocked by the Locker Service.